# The condition of the output of elements does not work

Tags: php, bitrix

I have any arrays:

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID", "DETAIL_PAGE_URL", "EDIT_LINK", "DELETE_LINK");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], "ACTIVE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "=PROPERTY_STATYS" => array(2,1), '=PROPERTY_LOT' => $arResult['ID']);
```

and output form:

```
<div class="panel-body second-links">
<?foreach ($arElement as $arElementItem):
if (($arSection['ID'] == $arElementItem['IBLOCK_SECTION_ID']) && ($arFilter['=PROPERTY_STATYS_VALUE'] == '1')):?>
<p>
    <a class="open_lot" href="javascript:void(0);" url="<?=$arElementItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']?>" idElement="<?=$arElementItem['ID']?>">
                    <?=$arElementItem['NAME']?>
    </a>
    <a>1</a>
</p>
    <?endif;
    endforeach;?>
</div>
```

condition does not work **$arFilter['=PROPERTY_STATYS'] == '1')** How correctly to put this condition?
With the condition that if the element of the array is 1 then output the text for example "1" and if "2" then the text 2 next to the main element.
var_dump(arFilter):

```
array(5) {
   ["IBLOCK_ID"]=> int(14)
   ["ACTIVE"]=> string(1) "Y"
   ["ACTIVE_DATE"]=> string(1) "Y"
   ["=PROPERTY_STATYS"]=> array(2) {
         [0]=> int(2)
         [1]=> int(1)
      }
      ["=PROPERTY_LOT"]=> NULL
  }
```

Comment: where is `PROPERTY_STATYS_VALUE ` ?

Comment: try to use in_array() function

Comment: @Ravi edit this. `PROPERTY_STATYS`

Answer (score 0):

you should use **($arElementItem['PROPERTY_STATYS_VALUE'] == '1')** condition instead of the one that you have used. The reason why is that $arFilter array is used to let database know how to filter items (this logic is done in component.php file). 
As for the output (it's usually in template.php) as you see you got a foreach loop and you can access to the item via $arElementItem.
Hope this helps - if not write me back, I'll fix this for sure.